# Failure building Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE from source

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I would like to build spring-boot 1.5.4.RELEASE. To do that I use the command

```
./mvnw clean install -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DskipTests=true
```

but I got the following problem (see below).

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-boot-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:tests:1.5.4.RELEASE in spring-ext (http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/) -> [Help 1]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Remove `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`, as it prevents creation of the needed `spring-boot` test-jar

Comment: Thanks.Well done.I got the right answer.